# Credit link that if removed stops site from working

Tags: licensing

Im trying add a credit link to the footer of all the WP sites i make saying:

*Designed by ...*

While this is simple enough, i want to code it so that if this link is removed from the footer, the entire site shows an error or doesn't load up etc.

Any one have ideas?

Comment: This is unethical and annoying. If you have to _force_ your users to show the link your product isn’t worth being used. Build great themes or plugins and make people proud to use it.

Comment: its not the clients removing it, after i sell the product(sites) larger web companies are hosting the site for them and changing the "Designed by" to their own site which is unethical. I'm a small company and i get work from these referral links.

Effectively its the same as using the free version of typekit and being forced to display their link. so please dont start to assume my products are not great.

Comment: Creative work is copyright, if you consider they are in effecting stealing your work, use the law based on your licensing, as Toscho said forcing people won't do anything, if you can code it, then people can remove it.

Comment: Reupvoted your question. I don't like what you want to do, but I like your heliskiing avatar. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ----------------  UPDATE  ----------------

I do some change of the code provide by @Rizier123

**Now it will accept to add a link in the citation varibale**

You need to change the line of **preg_match** ( Thanks goes to @Rizier123) by this :

```
if(!preg_match("/" . preg_quote($citation_string, "/") . "/", $footer_contents))
```

so the final code will be like this :

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'foobar_explode_if_no_citation');
function foobar_explode_if_no_citation(){

#Get the absolute server path to footer.php
$footer_path = locate_template('footer.php');

#Store the footer file contents in a var
$footer_contents = file_get_contents($footer_path);

#The required string
$citation_string = 'Designed by Foo Bar <a href="http://YourLink.com">anchor</a>';

#Set off the nuclear bomb if there is an egregious offense
if(!preg_match("/" . preg_quote($citation_string, "/") . "/", $footer_contents))
    exit('All your websitez are belong to me. Make sure this string "Designed by Foo Bar" is included in footer.php');
}
```

**? Who will work with this code ?**

coders who **worked days and night** to provide great content, and just putting their citation words or link as a copyright..and dont want a user of the script **remove it or replace it** with his own **without permission**...

**it's just a simple way to respect the copyright! respect coders.**

Comment: @Matt This guy stole my answer and you gave him the accept? He should have edited mine.

Comment: @Matt This guy posted my answer as a question to get your answer. He had others do work for him. Bad player. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189117/probleme-adding-txt-and-links-in-preg-match

Answer (score 1):

While I believe the premise of this to be flawed and somewhat black-hat, it is a legit WP question albeit a futile exercise.

You can do something like the following:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'foobar_explode_if_no_citation');
function foobar_explode_if_no_citation(){

    #Get the absolute server path to footer.php
    $footer_path = locate_template('footer.php');

    #Store the footer file contents in a var
    $footer_contents = file_get_contents($footer_path);

    #The required string
    $citation_string = 'Designed by Foo Bar';

    #Set off the nuclear bomb if there is an egregious offense
    if(!preg_match("/$citation_string/", $footer_contents))
        exit('All your websitez are belong to me. Make sure this string "Designed by Foo Bar" is included in footer.php');
}
```

I hope you get my tongue-in-cheek innuendoes regarding what a bad user experience this would be. :)

### Caveat

As noted in the comments, there are innumerable ways to route this approach, and any approach for that matter. Anyone can easily reverse engineer any mechanism put in place.

Comment: `<!-- Designed by Foo Bar -->`

Comment: @toscho Yes, this code will need to account for all shenanigans.

Comment: You don’t even know if the plain `footer.php` will be used by the theme. :) `get_footer( 'rebranded' );`

Comment: @toscho I mainly created this as a proof-of-concept. I realize there are a gazillion ways to get around this. My answer was mainly to show what a nightmare this would actually be to accomplish something like this. Hence, my tongue-in-cheek reference. This whole concept is not maintainable at all.