# probleme adding Txt and Links in preg_match()

Tags: php

I'm newbie in PHP, i use this PHP code who work as a charm (@Brian Fegter) :

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'foobar_explode_if_no_citation');
function foobar_explode_if_no_citation(){

    #Get the absolute server path to footer.php
    $footer_path = locate_template('footer.php');

    #Store the footer file contents in a var
    $footer_contents = file_get_contents($footer_path);

    #The required string
    $citation_string = 'Designed by Foo Bar';

    #Set off the nuclear bomb if there is an egregious offense
    if(!preg_match("/$citation_string/", $footer_contents))
        exit('All your websitez are belong to me. Make sure this string "Designed by Foo Bar" is included in footer.php');
}
```

I try to add some txt and links in this line

```
$citation_string = 'Designed by Foo Bar';
```

to be

```
$citation_string = 'this is my txt and this is my url <a href="http://url.com">anchor</a>';
```

but i have this **warning** :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to escape `/` symbols inside your string. Please not that this falls on the side of unspecific to WordPress and is better asked at [so].

Comment: Also, this is a pretty cheap trick. Thank you for letting me know to never use your products.

Comment: @Rarst Thanks for your reply,
i delet the `/` symbols, and i add the url inside the string :

`$citation_string = 'http://my-url.com';`

I have this errour :

`Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash ...`

Pls what's the solution.
Thanks

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: @TaghaBoy You need to learn how to use StackExchange. Stop stealing answers from other questions and posting them as questions to answer other questions. If you can't answer a question on your own, stop answering. Don't get other people to do your work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally a solution provide by @Rizier123

```
if(!preg_match("/" . preg_quote($citation_string, "/") . "/", $footer_contents))
```

@Rizier123 say : The problem are the slashes in your pattern, just use **preg_quote()** to escape them, e.g.

so the code will be like this :

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'foobar_explode_if_no_citation');
function foobar_explode_if_no_citation(){

#Get the absolute server path to footer.php
$footer_path = locate_template('footer.php');

#Store the footer file contents in a var
$footer_contents = file_get_contents($footer_path);

#The required string
$citation_string = 'Designed by Foo Bar <a href="http://YourLink.com">anchor</a>';

#Set off the nuclear bomb if there is an egregious offense
if(!preg_match("/" . preg_quote($citation_string, "/") . "/", $footer_contents))
    exit('All your websitez are belong to me. Make sure this string "Designed by Foo Bar" is included in footer.php');
}
```

**? Who will work with this code ?**

coders who **worked days and night** to provide great content, and just putting their citation words or link as a copyright..and dont want a user of the script **remove it or replace it** with his own **without permission**...

**it's just a simple way to respect the copyright! respect coders.**

Comment: That is a infringement of the [WordPress license itself (GPLv2 or later)](https://wordpress.org/about/license/), you should respect that in first place if you want that other respect your work based on WordPress. You can not apply any restriction on the way of final user uses the product. You can read the content of GPLv3 (latest version at this moment) license [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html).

Comment: @cybmeta : You must understand BEFORE your give -1 to my answer.the script it's for coders who create website for business, so it's not free. Before I create any work i ask first to keep the copyright, or add more fees to delete it. In my last work the webmaster of the company he is removed my copyright and add his own! so i'll lost potential customers... so WHO code all the time days and night!!! me or the webmaster? Sir i just protect my work, my business.

Comment: I have nothing to say, you should read the license of WordPress. You can charge customers to get a copy of your software or to get support but you can not restrict how the final user uses the product; you can put a backlink in the footer, but can not force to the customer to keep that link. That are the terms of the WordPress license that apply to any derivative work like your work. WordPress is possible because many coders work during thousands of hours to build a free platform you can use in your business. I repeat, if you want that others respect your work, respect the work of others first.

Comment: Powered by WordPress - Designed by me ... this is not the respect of each other !!! i'm not forcing customer to keep my link... but forcing others do not change my link to his link...and without a backlink i'll lose my job, and thanks to keep -1

Comment: No, it is not, it not respecting the terms of WordPress license if you force the final user, customer or not, to use the product in a scpecific way. Anyway, this is not the right place to discuss this topic. You can read a lot of threads about that in wordpress.org foums, for example [this one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/which-license-to-use-for-a-paid-plugin).